# Rollback part of an edit without offense

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

At my steep learning curve, I was wondering whether I could rollback a part of an edit (such as removal of a tag that I think decreased the attention) of the post?

While I understand that the edits are being handled by more experienced members, how would I rollback or suggest a rollback of part of the edit without being offensive?

Comment: You will do well here :p

Answer (score 21):

You can simply edit your post manually and readd the tag, as the question author you can always edit your own posts (unless a diamond moderator locks it).

But if an experienced user removed that tag, you should look closely at your question again if that tag actually applies to your question. They likely had a good reason to remove the tag, but even high-reputation members are not infallible. You could also politely ask why they removed the tag if you don't see a reason for it by writing a comment with `@username` on your own post.

Comment: That makes absolute sense. I was afraid, as a slow started, that than may get misinterpreted as offensive. Good advice.

Answer (score 11):

An edit that consists of only re-adding a tag is probably a bad choice.

The reason that a high-reputation user would remove a tag is because the body of your question led them to believe that the tag was not appropriate.  The correct thing to do is **edit the body of the question to provide some detail about how that particular technology is being used, and how it relates to the code where the problem occurs**, and also re-add the tag.

At the same time, take a closer look at the relationship of the tagged technology to your problem.  Is the problem related to the tag, or is it incidental, an accident of chance that both appear in the same problem.  More experienced users may be able to immediately see the actual cause when you are only wondering.  Or you may be fully convinced that it is related, and still be wrong.

Describing where code fits into a larger program can be quite useful to answerers, since it helps solve the "X-Y problem".  But that doesn't mean technologies from other parts of the program should appear in your tags.